# How can i align the image at center?CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this example:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/

This is code HTMl:

```
    <div class="wrap">

    <div class="wrap1">
<div class="image1">This is some text</div>
<div class="image2">This is some text</div>
<div class="image3">This is some text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="image4">This is some text</div>
    <div class="image5">This is some text</div>


</div>
```

This is code CSS:

```
.image1,.image2,.image3{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  margin-left:auto;

}

.image4,.image5
{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
}
.wrap1{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.wrap
{   border:1px solid;
    width:700px;
}
```

How can i align the image at center?

I want all the images to be aligned in the middle inside the square which has a border

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you need all image to center of border box. 
 Use  `text-align:center` in wrap class:

```
.wrap
{   border:1px solid;
    width:700px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tn2bukno/).

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```css
.image{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  margin-left:auto;

}
.wrap
{  
   border:1px solid;
    width:700px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrap">

    <div class="wrap1">
      <div class="image">This is some text</div>
      <div class="image">This is some text</div>
      <div class="image">This is some text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="image">This is some text</div>
    <div class="image">This is some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

For example background-position: center;

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/1xfyLcfs/)